# how to find what macro name has been assigned to an object in excel

Tags: excel, object, vba

I'm working on a spread sheet that someone else created and am having trouble in identifying which macros are assigned to the different objects.  When I right click to :assign", it doesn't tell me what is already assigned.  Is there a way to find out?

Comment: What kind of objects?

Answer (score 2):

When you right click and select `Assign Macro` it should have the macro name already entered in the cell at the top, above the list of available macros. Alternatively clicking `Edit` should take you to the code. This works for Excel 2007 - you don't stipulate which you are using.

As a last resort, assuming you don't have masses and masses of macros, go to the VBE and put a break (click in the left margin to make it highlighted red) on the first line of each Sub/ Macro, then when you click the object it will take you to the VBE and highlight the line it stopped and thus the macro assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects the macro assigned to is grouped, excel doesn't show the macro assigned. Ungrouping objects will allow you to see which individual item actually has the macro assigned.